# How to read a TBlobfield from a query

Tags: delphi, blob, delphi-xe5, firedac

Here is my problem.
I have a MS ACCESS  table  (`id` , `firstname`,  `name`, `file`). The `file` field is of OLE object type and contains a `pdf` file for each record.

I am using DELPHI XE 5 and  FireDAC as  data components (`TFDConnection`,  `TFDTable`,  `TFDQuery`). I am able to store data in the `file`  field  but not able to read it.

When I use `TFDQuery` I am   not able to read data in the `file`  field. Here is what a did to read:

```
procedure TForm1.Button8Click(Sender: TObject);
var fx:TmemoryStream;   bl:TBlobField;
begin
    fx:=TMemoryStream.create;
    query1.open;

    bl:= TBlobField (query1.FieldByName('file')) ;
    
    bl.SaveToStream(fx);    
    fx.SaveToFile('c:\exportedfile.pdf');
    fx.free;
end;
```

The script  works but the problem  is that the file is exported as a 4kb  unreadable  file,  while its real size is more than  100kb. There is no such problem if I use a `TFDTable`.

Comment: Thanks for everybody who answered my question.

Comment: the problem is with FireDAC components,  the code works fine with TFDTable and not with TFDQuery.

Comment: i've tried both of the proposed answers they don't work with TFDQuery. either i get an exported unreadable file with 4 bytes in size or i get an error message "invalid pointer operation".